How to Retrieve lost ppk file in AWS
We hosted our WordPress site on AWS. The website is working fine.
But we lost the ppk file to connect to SSH.
Is there any way to retrieve the lost ppk file in AWS?

No. You could use session manager to connect to the instance over an ssh like connection, then add a key inside the operating system. Here's a link I happen to have that applies to Raspberry Pi, it's much the same for Linux on AWS https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-ssh-keys/

it showing : "SSM agent is not online : https://imgur.com/a/vaAviZS

You'll need to stop your instance, mount the volume as a data volume to another temporary instance, add an ssh key, stop the temporary instance, mount the volume back to your original instance, then start it. There's probably a longer form tutorial around somewhere.
